# My Dell Inspiron 8600 WiFi Won't Work

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

The wireless internet connection on my Dell Inspiron 8500 isn't working. I was told to get WiFi on it that I need to remove the BCMWX kernel module and Install a B43-something. Is this right? What does this advice mean and how can I do it?

Comment: Please run `lspci -v`, look through the output, and post the block that looks like it describes your wireless card. If you can't see which that is. post the whole output somewhere like pastebin and link it here.

Comment: That whole thing just confused me more...

Comment: So is it Inpiron 8600 or 8500? There are answers for both, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

On an Inspiron 8600, the wireless chip is identified as BCM4309. Its id is [14e4:4324](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11678920&postcount=5). To work, it needs a driver. To install this driver, open Software Center and search for **firmware-b43-installer**.

I don't know about a driver called bcmwx, but there is one called wl. To be rid of it, open Software Center and make sure **broadcom-sta-common** is **not** installed.

Answer (score 0):

On an Inspiron 8500, the wireless chip is identified as BCM4306. Its id is [14e4:4320](http://www.technickal.net/node/6). There are two revisions of this chip, numbered 2 and 3. Revision 2 works with **firmware-b43legacy-installer** from the Software Center. Revision 3 works with **firmware-b43-installer** from the Software Center.

Open the Software Center and try either of them, but make sure both are not installed at the same time.

I don't know about a driver called bcmwx, but there is one called wl. To be rid of it, open Software Center and make sure **broadcom-sta-common** is **not** installed.